# Left - align tab labels in JavaFX fixed-width tabpane

Tags: java, css, javafx, tabs, javafx-8

When creating a tabpane with a defined min-tab-width, JavaFX will center the label of each tab.

Is there a way to left-align the label? I've tried this:

```
package prv.rli.codetest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabPaneFixedWidthLeftAligned extends Application {

    public TabPaneFixedWidthLeftAligned() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TabPane pane = new TabPane();
        pane.setTabMinWidth(150);
        pane.getTabs().addAll(new Tab("Bilbo"), new Tab("Baggins"));
        pane.getStylesheets().add("file:///home/rli/devel/repository/source/java/project/apps/CodeTest/src/main/java/prv/rli/codetest/test.css");
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

together with this css:

```
.tab-container {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
    -fx-text-alignment: left;       
}
```

while the background colors work (indicating I'm on the right track) I am unable to influence the text alignment of the label.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by setting the following properties:

```
.tab-pane
{
    -fx-tab-min-width: 150.0px;
}

.tab .tab-label
{
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
```

See also this answer on StackOverflow: [Change JavaFx Tab default Look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788661/change-javafx-tab-default-look)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resize `.tab-label`

```
.tab-label { 
    -fx-pref-width:150; 
    /* ... other styles*/
}
```