# Spacing between tabs

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to add spacing between tabs?
Here's an image:
[image]

I would like to add a space between "Presentation" tab and "testgame", any help?
Here's the css I'm using:

```
* {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;

    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;

    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

/* tabs */

.tab {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#9b2626, #721b1b);
    -fx-border-color: #721b1b;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.tab:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #9b2626;
}

.tab:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: #721b1b;
}
```

Comment: Use an invisible border maybe?? I don't know of a default method.

Comment: The problem is that I already use a border...

Comment: `margin` maybe helpful, not sure much about that.

Comment: Take a look at the answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788661/change-javafx-tab-default-look)

Comment: Can you post the CSS you are using, and a simple [MCVE] that uses it?

Comment: @loryruta Where is the [MCVE]? I don't even know what kind of thing has the `"presentationTab"` id...

Comment: Don't care about it, I've removed it and works as well as before. It was just the id of the presentation tab (you would be able to get it alone..)

Comment: So the colors were only applied to one tab? That doesn't make sense with your screenshot - both tabs seem to have the same style.

Comment: Think if #presentationTab doesn't exist I don't know why it was doing it but that's not important. I removed it and the issue is the same: tabs has no spacing each other.

Comment: Well I can hardly apply your CSS to something if I don't know what it's supposed to be applied to. It's your problem that you want a solution to, though.

Comment: This css is applied to the root and the part I gave you is the entire css I'm not hiding you anything, and I don't know how to space tables.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult here. Anyone who provides a decent answer to this is going to do so by testing out their solution. (Else they are just providing guesses.) To do that, they need a simple example to test it on. So you're basically asking someone to write their own example to solve *your* problem, even though you won't provide one yourself. (And even then there may be subtle differences which prevent the solution they provide from working in the scenario in which you want it to work.)

Comment: I think that the things I've given are enough, the rest is the fxml file but I don't think that is there te problem... If someone wants to test my issue just create a tabpane put the css I've given and he will see my issue. What should I put more?

Comment: I'm just giving you advice on how to make it easier to get help. The other thing that will encourage people to help you is if you mark some answers to other questions you've posted as "correct", if they helped. As for: *"If someone wants to test my issue just create a tabpane put the css I've given"*, don't you think it would be polite for *you* to do that bit, since it's *your* problem you want help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but try using nested backgrounds instead of your border. That way you can have a transparent background extending on one side, creating the appearance of a space.

```
* {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;

    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;

    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
}

/* presentation tab */

.tab {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, tab-border-color , tab-color;
    tab-color: linear-gradient(light-tab-color, dark-tab-color) ;
    tab-border-color : dark-tab-color ;
    dark-tab-color: #721b1b ;
    light-tab-color: #9b2626 ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 5 0 0, 1 6 0 0 ;
    -fx-padding: 4 10 4 4 ;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.tab:hover {
    tab-color: light-tab-color ;
}

.tab:pressed {
    tab-color: dark-tab-color;
}
```

Comment: All works as I said, but could you explain it? I would be really pleased.

Comment: There are three backgrounds, with different colors, painted on top of each other. There are three corresponding insets. So the transparent background has zero insets, the background with the border color has a 5 pixel inset on the right only (0 on the other sides), and the background with the tab-color is inset a further one pixel on the top and right, relative to the border color. Just draw a picture with those superimposed and you'll see the effect is a 1-pixel border on the top and right, and a 5 pixel transparent gap on the right. The padding ensures the content doesn't escape the border.

Answer (score -1):

```
.tab {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 3 0 3;
}
```

The first 0 is the top spacing

Second 0 corresponds spacing to the right

Third 0 is the bottom spacing

Finally, fourth 0 is the spacing to the left

Don't forget to add this code to a CSS file and attach it to your tabPane or tab with

```
tabPane.getStylesheets().add("path/to/your/stylesheet.css");
```

Alternatively, you can simply

```
tab.setStyle("-fx-background-insets: 0 3 0 3;");
```

Before:
[image]

After: [image]

Please note that I'm not explicitly setting spacing between tabs. Instead, as a workaround, the gap between tabs is increased by removing (in this case) 3 pixels from the left and right side of the Tab.

Comment: well, the question is about spacing _between_ tabs - changing the bottom inset is ... ;) Also setting insets alone is not enough for the appearance of additional space (see the accepted answer)

Comment: _I kindly ask you to test my code_ well, I did (my memory might have failed me ;) - before commenting: the outcome was that it's not working in the sense of the question (that is increase space between tabs, that's not happening) Anyway, you might want to improve your answer with a [mcve] (using one of the snippets) to demonstrate its effect

Comment: @kleopatra, sure, I'll be doing that soon, let me know your thoughts once I finish (I'll tag you here once again). Thanks for pointing my error

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do add padding or set the space.

```
  // VBox
VBox vb = new VBox();
vb.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 50, 50));
vb.setSpacing(10);
```

Comment: I am not aware if it is possible through css, if you find out git me a heads up.

Comment: insect the spacing between nodes in javafx by pixels here is the constructor Insets(double top,   double right, double bottom, double left),

Comment: padding makes the tab bigger and spacing seems to do anything... (I've put tab and spacing into the Tab or ".tab" style)